# In iOS: Can my app launch another app and get a response/acknowledgement back?

Tags: iphone, ios, swift

In iOS, is there anyway i can launch another app to do something and then get a response back saying that it’s done.

For example: My iOS app APP A launches another app APP B (e.g. Google Pay) to make a payment and then after the payment is made, I would like APP A to receive a response/callback/acknowledgement saying its done.

By the way, I'm having zero trouble getting APP A to launch APP B via UIApplication.Shared.Open(…)

** In android we use Android Intent to launch APP B and get a response back to APP A using OnActivityResult(…)**.

PS: My App is actually built in React Native using NativeModules.

Thanks

Comment: You probably want to ask this question on SO, not here.

Comment: This is definitely possible, but the scope of the site limits programming questions and  stackoverflow should be the site to ask. As for where it happens, there's a VPN app I use, which takes me to settings → VPN, I authenticate the VPN configuration, and then come back to the app. 
Another way is to use this native feature: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbUgZm.jpg
Another way for such inter-app interaction is using the APIs the target app supports. For e.g., when you chose to share a link via messages, you get the messages overlay: `MFMessageComposeViewController`.

Answer (score 1):

## Custom URL Schemes

You can define and use a custom URL scheme to interact with other apps on iOS:

### [Defining a Custom URL Scheme for Your App](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/inter-process_communication/allowing_apps_and_websites_to_link_to_your_content/defining_a_custom_url_scheme_for_your_app)

> Custom URL schemes provide a way to reference resources inside your app. Users tapping a custom URL in an email, for example, launch your app in a specified context. Other apps can also trigger your app to launch with specific context data; for example, a photo library app might display a specified image.